# Reindexing timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, python-datetime, reindex

I have an issue similar to ["ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711623/valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis).The solution isn't provided.

I have an excel file containing multiple rows and columns of weather data. Data has missing at certain intervals although not shown in the sample below. I want to reindex the time column at 5 minute intervals so that I can interpolate the missing values. Data Sample:

---

```
Date        Time    Temp    Hum Dewpnt  WindSpd
04/01/18    12:05 a 30.6    49  18.7    2.7
04/01/18    12:10 a NaN     51  19.3    1.3
04/01/18    12:20 a 30.7   NaN  19.1    2.2
04/01/18    12:30 a 30.7    51  19.4    2.2 
04/01/18    12:40 a 30.9    51  19.6    0.9
```

---

Here's what I have tried.

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.read_excel('E:\DATA\AP.xlsx')
ts['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['Time'])
ts.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
dt = pd.date_range("2018-04-01 00:00:00", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", freq='5min', name='T')
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt)
ts.reindex(idx)
```

I just just want to have my index at 5 min frequency so that I can interpolate the NaN later. **Expected output:**

```
Date        Time    Temp    Hum Dewpnt  WindSpd
04/01/18    12:05 a 30.6    49  18.7    2.7
04/01/18    12:10 a NaN     51  19.3    1.3
04/01/18    12:15 a NaN   NaN  NaN     NaN
04/01/18    12:20 a 30.7   NaN  19.1    2.2
04/01/18    12:25 a NaN   NaN  NaN     NaN
04/01/18    12:30 a 30.7    51  19.4    2.2
```

Comment: provide your input data & expected output as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Made the suggested changes.

Answer (score 2):

One more approach.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index(['Time']).resample('5min').last().reset_index()
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
df
```

**output**

```
       Time     Date        Temp    Hum     Dewpnt  WindSpd
0   00:05:00    4/1/2018    30.6    49.0    18.7    2.7
1   00:10:00    4/1/2018    NaN     51.0    19.3    1.3
2   00:15:00    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   00:20:00    4/1/2018    30.7    NaN     19.1    2.2
4   00:25:00    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   00:30:00    4/1/2018    30.7    51.0    19.4    2.2
6   00:35:00    NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   00:40:00    4/1/2018    30.9    51.0    19.6    0.9
```

If times from multiple dates have to be re-sampled, you can use code below.

However, you will have to seperate 'Date' & 'Time' columns later.

```
df1['DateTime'] = df1['Date']+df1['Time']
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime'],format='%d/%m/%Y%I:%M %p')
df1 = df1.set_index(['DateTime']).resample('5min').last().reset_index()
df1
```

**Output**

```
DateTime    Date    Time    Temp    Hum     Dewpnt  WindSpd
0   2018-01-04 00:05:00     4/1/2018    12:05 AM    30.6    49.0    18.7    2.7
1   2018-01-04 00:10:00     4/1/2018    12:10 AM    NaN     51.0    19.3    1.3
2   2018-01-04 00:15:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   2018-01-04 00:20:00     4/1/2018    12:20 AM    30.7    NaN     19.1    2.2
4   2018-01-04 00:25:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   2018-01-04 00:30:00     4/1/2018    12:30 AM    30.7    51.0    19.4    2.2
6   2018-01-04 00:35:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   2018-01-04 00:40:00     4/1/2018    12:40 AM    30.9    51.0    19.6    0.9
```

Comment: It is working but the output seems to have only the last 1 day data (last day April). How can it be modified to include the whole dataset? I think both the Date and time columns need to be combined.

Comment: I have got it to work with helpful suggestions from your answer. Added the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for example:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.read_excel('E:\DATA\AP.xlsx')
ts['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['Time'])
ts.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
ts.resample('5T').mean()
```

More information here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I am not getting the error but the dataset hasn't been resampled as the output is same as the input.

Comment: ts.interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)

Comment: Output does not have values at the new intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Time column as the index, making sure it is DateTime type, then try

```
ts.asfreq('5T')
```

use

```
ts.asfreq('5T', method='ffill')
```

to pull previous values forward.

Comment: I already had 'time' as the index and Date Time type. I am getting the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach of creating a blank table and fill it in with the data as it comes from your data source. For this example three observations are read in as NaN, plus the row for 1:15 and 1:20 is missing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rawpd = pd.read_excel('raw.xlsx')
print(rawpd)
```

```
    Date      Time  Col1  Col2
```

0 2018-04-01  01:00:00   1.0  10.0
1 2018-04-01  01:05:00   2.0  NaN 
2 2018-04-01  01:10:00   NaN  10.0
3 2018-04-01  01:20:00   NaN  10.0
4 2018-04-01  01:30:00   5.0  10.0

Now create a dataframe targpd with the ideal structure.

```
time5min = pd.date_range(start='2018/04/1 01:00',periods=7,freq='5min')
targpd = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,index = time5min,columns=['Col1','Col2'])
print(targpd)
```

```
                 Col1  Col2
```

2018-04-01 01:00:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:05:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:10:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:15:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:20:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:25:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:30:00   NaN   NaN 

Now the trick is to update targpd with the data sent to you in rawpd. For this to happen the Date and Time columns have to be combined in rawpd and made into an index.

```
print(rawpd.Date,rawpd.Time)
```

0   2018-04-01
1   2018-04-01
2   2018-04-01
3   2018-04-01
4   2018-04-01

Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns] 
0    01:00:00
1    01:05:00 
2    01:10:00 
3    01:20:00 
4    01:30:00 
Name: Time, dtype: object 

You can see above the trick in all this. Your date data was converted to datetime but your time data is just a string. Below a proper index is created by used of a **lambda** function.

```
rawidx=rawpd.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['Date'],r['Time']),1)
print(rawidx)
```

This can be applied to the rawpd database as an index.

```
rawpd2=pd.DataFrame(rawpd[['Col1','Col2']].values,index=rawidx,columns=['Col1','Col2'])
rawpd2=rawpd2.sort_index()
print(rawpd2)
```

Once this is in place the update command can get you what you want.

```
targpd.update(rawpd2,overwrite=True)
print(targpd)
```

```
                 Col1  Col2
```

2018-04-01 01:00:00   1.0  10.0  
2018-04-01 01:00:00   1.0  10.0  
2018-04-01 01:05:00   2.0   NaN  
2018-04-01 01:10:00   NaN  10.0  
2018-04-01 01:15:00   NaN   NaN  
2018-04-01 01:20:00   NaN  10.0 
2018-04-01 01:25:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:30:00   5.0  10.0 
2018-04-01 01:05:00   2.0   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:10:00   NaN  10.0 
2018-04-01 01:15:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:20:00   NaN  10.0 
2018-04-01 01:25:00   NaN   NaN 
2018-04-01 01:30:00   5.0  10.0

You now have a file ready for interpolation

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error when running rawpd2.  KeyError: "None of [Index(['Col1', 'Col2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"      Everything is fine until then.

Comment: lambda functions can be tough to debug.  I would look for a typo like 'col1' versus 'Col1'

Answer (score 0):

I have got it to work. thank you everyone for your time. I am providing the working code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('E:\DATA\AP.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
df = df.set_index(['Date_Time']).resample('5min').last().reset_index()
print(df)
```